# Is using connection.commit() from pymysql more frequently to AWS RDS more expensive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pymysql

I'm assuming that the more commits I make to my database, the more put requests I make. Would it be less expensive to commit less frequently (but commit larger queries at a time)?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're either using RDS for MySQL or MySQL-Compatible Aurora; in either case, you're charged based on the number of running hours, storage and I/O rate, and data transferred OUT of the service (Aurora Serverless pricing is a different story).
In RDS, you're not charged by PUT requests, and there is not such a concept with pymysql.

**The frequency of commits should be primarily driven by your application functional requirements**, not cost. Let's break it down to give you a better idea of how each cost variable would relate to each approach (commit big batches less frequently vs. commit small batches more frequently).

- Running hours: Irrelevant, same for both approaches.
- Storage: Irrelevant, you'll probably consume the same amount of storage. The amount of data is constant.
- I/O rate: There are many factors involved in how the DB engine consumes/optimizes I/O. I wouldn't get to this level of granularity.
- Data transferred IN: Irrelevant, free for both cases.